# Sending email programatically using the DEFAULT app

Tags: android, email, default, send

I am developing an app that send programatically an email, Im using stoxk LG mail

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{XXXXXXX});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "XXXXXXXXXX");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , (" XXXXXXXX"));


    try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending mail..."));



} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();



    finish();
}
```

It opens the LG mail and pastes the SUBJECT, the TEXT and the MAIL BUT it doesn't send it , how can I achieve it?

Anny suggestion will be apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With intent you can't do this.

But look at the link, there is an answer for your question.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default android app(Builtin Email application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Thank you. But I want to use the default,  is it posible?

Comment: No, it isn't possible without user button press

Comment: Thank you anyway I will have a look at that.